# How to change 3D Object Node Position Change in ARCore?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to set Node Position (one here as example):

```
faceNode.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(faceNode.getLocalPosition().x, (float) (faceNode.getLocalPosition().y+22.2), (float) (faceNode.getLocalPosition().z-50)));
```

But the results always same.

Comment: What is the "always same" result? Share more information.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
model?.thenAccept {
                                        val badge = Node()
                                        val localPosition = Vector3()
                                        localPosition.set(0.0f, -0.25f, 0.0f)
                                        badge.localScale = Vector3(-0.12f, 0.12f, 0.12f)
//                                    badge.localRotation = Quaternion.axisAngle(Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 180f)
                                        badge.localPosition = localPosition
                                        badge.setParent(faceNode)
                                        badge.renderable = it
                                    
                                }
```

It's part of some code I wrote [here](https://gptshubham595.medium.com/unveiling-the-world-of-ar-with-arcore-my-journey-of-exploration-practical-guide-86ac7f54b34).